# Overriding ASP.NET DropDownList width for responsive website

Tags: html, asp.net, css, responsive-design

If there's a case for using MVC for responsive websites, this is it:

I'm working on a site that is mostly ASP.NET WebForms, which is undergoing a redesign to use responsive markup. It is impractical to convert everything to MVC, so I have to make do with the existing controls.

On a particular form page, we have two combo-boxes on the same row; these have CSS classes appropriately set to specify the width at `48%` of the parent element. The trouble is that since we're using the **asp:DropDownList**, the control is rendered with a `style` attribute having `width:275px;`, which overrides the width set in the CSS class.

In codebehind of the composite control containing these DropDownLists (particularly the `RenderChildren` method override), I've tried calling `[control].Style.Clear();` prior to calling the base method. This has no effect; even adding:

```
[control].Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Width, "inherit");
```

causes the element to be rendered as:

```
<select style="width:275px;width:inherit;" class="input-half first" id="longAndComplicated" name="longAndComplicated">
```

Note the two `width` declarations, when ideally there shouldn't be a `style` attribute in the first place.

I've had a poke in Reflector at the source, and couldn't find where this hard-coded width is being set; I gather that the style setters are being copied from somewhere further up the ASP.NET hierarchy.

As a lucky guess, I tried:

- Setting `Width` to an empty string on the `<asp:DropDownList>` ("inherit" causes a Parse error)
- Explicitly specifying `Width="48%"`
- Setting `EnableTheming="false"`

None of these has had any positive effect, with the rendered `style` attribute still having `width:275px;`.

Where is this width magically being set from? How can I override this behaviour, ideally without having to create a derived class inheriting from `System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList`?

Many thanks.

Comment: Set a breakpoint in RenderChildren and check whether the Width of the DropDownList has been set to 275px. The standard DropDownList control does not hard-code any width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doh - I figured out what it was.

It turns out that the containing composite control defined properties along the lines of `DropDown1Width` and `DropDown2Width`. These 'cleverly' set the `Width` property of the underlying `DropDownList` controls, which were used during the `DropDownList.Render()` method.

Fortunately I don't have to go subclassing `DropDownList`, though in hindsight the lack of definitive web search results suggested the problem was likely to be somewhere in our own codebase.

I say "defined", as I have since removed these redundant properties (and their corresponding assignments in various ASPX files).

Answer (score 0):

I have better Idea, fix the width and **do not inherit** the width, as that will inherit width from parent and over-ride the width element defined with width:275px; so that will be meaning less.

I have created a fiddle, works fine in chrome, the select tag has fixed width,

If sub element size will increase it will automatically grow.

Please check [`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/MarmeeK/PxCwP/)

If your question is referring to CSS class `class="input-half first"` then the style defined in element style is the one what is applied at last and will have high priority compare to class, better create new class, and assign it.

Hope, I have answered in right context as you have written many things with reference to ASP.net control, but I don't think that should be problem in majority cases.

Comment: Thanks, though that isn't my issue. The problem is that I don't want a `style` attribute to be set in the first place (because it overrides the width set in the `input-half` class), which is what ASP.NET is doing.

Comment: THat is not ASP.net, its CSS general precedence for style. give and example of problem. Will help to solve